# SQL server, how to concat a dymanic (unknown) amout of strings with a single query

Tags: sql-server

I know how to concact two strings, but this one will be a bit more complicated, i guess it's a duplicate but i could not find it after an hour of search so....

Suppose i have a table like this :

```
ExempleTable
____________________
  ID   |  TEXT      |
___________________ |
 1     |  'hello '  |
 2     |  'how are '|
 3     |  'you ?'   |
```

I need a select that would return a single line containing :

```
'hello how are you ?'
```

I thought something like this would exist :

```
CONCATTEXT( SELECT text FROM ExampleTable) as sentence
```

But no... maybe it's a `GROUP BY` matter ? I can't figure it out...

Comment: Do you really have those single quotes in records

Comment: The quotes dosen't exist actualy

Comment: No... guys, i'm asking if it's possible to do it in a single query, not by all means with temporary tables and everything, if it's not possible in a single query well... too bad

Comment: See the one marked by @Siyual. The reason those temp tables are used is to create a table for the query. Just use your actual table there instead of the temp table.

Comment: None of those methods used temporary tables outside of generating test data.

Comment: ok sorry just by looking at it, it seemed more complicated, i will take a second look

Comment: @Siyual in fact it's pretty much like my question, i accepted mine as duplicate

Comment: WITH rquery (testid, sentence)                                    
AS                            
( SELECT  base.testid, base.text                                  
  FROM testtable base                                                  
  WHERE testid = 1                        
  UNION ALL   
  SELECT t1.testid, trim(sentence) || ' ' || trim(t1.text)        
  FROM rquery t0, testtable t1                                         
  WHERE   
        t0.testid + 1 = t1.testid                                 
)SELECT * FROM rquery where testid= (select max(testid) from  rquery  )

Comment: @ABove works perfectly

Comment: @vijayksingh.vj did you accidentaly post here ???????

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: No checkout the query. Its small and concatenates column values into a single row

Comment: Yeah might be ok, nice work, Jhon Cappelletti's query is a bit more simple though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,TEXT varchar(50))
 Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'hello '),
 (2,'how are '),
 (3,'you ?')

Select Stuff((Select ' '+ltrim(rtrim(Text)) From @YourTable Order by ID For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
```

Returns

```
hello how are you ?
```

Comment: can't use this, SINGLE QUERY

Comment: See Edit Select Stuff((

Comment: Thank you, this exemple is very simple, sorry my question was a duplicate

Comment: @AntoinePelletier see update. I added ltrim(rtrim(text)) to avoid double spaces

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Happy it helped

Comment: strange though it made some tags appear : `<BLOC_TEXT>` and `&#x0D` like it was html or something, not that it matters much i can remove them easely

Comment: @AntoinePelletier You must have some extended characters/tags in your data.  Data-Hygiene is a constant battle :)

Comment: Yeah i see... Data-Hygiene, funny word, strong meaning

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable:

```
declare @result varchar(max) = ''

select @result += field + ' ' from T

select rtrim(@result)
```

Comment: No i can't use variable